# Concurrent request processing in Java with constraints

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

Suppose I need to process requests of 3 types: A, B, and C as follows:

- Requests are processed concurrently.
- There are *at most* K (<= 3) requests to be processed concurrently at the same time.
- Requests of *the same type* cannot be processed at the same time.

More generally, the number of types is N and the number of concurrent requests is K <= N.

How would you implement it in Java with `java.util.concurrent`?

Answer (score 2):

You can not process K requests at the same time, that will break second rule. Maximum number of concurrent requests is number types. In your case its three. So make three queues and attache them to three threads. Thats the only way. [Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor%28%29) implements this technique.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N = 2;
    int K = 3;
    List<Executor> executors = new ArrayList<Executor>(N);
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        executors.add(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
    }
    Map<Type, Executor> typeExecutors = new HashMap<Type, Executor>(K);
    int i = 0;
    for(Type t : Type.values()){
        typeExecutors.put(t, executors.get(i++ % executors.size()));
    }
}

enum Type{
    T1, T2, T3
}
```

Comment: Agree, after the first read through the question I was thinking Executors as well (newFixedThreadPool of size k). However the constraing of only having a maximum of 1 job of a certain type run at a any given moment makes your threads+queues proposition much better.

Comment: What if K = 2 ? More generally the number of types is N and K < N. I will update the question.

Comment: So, make K thread and split all type queues between them. For case K=2, N=3. First thread should poll two queses in round robin fashion, for example, while second one listens only to a single queue.

Comment: I do not like polling :(

Comment: Use one of BlockingQueue implementations though. It has a take() method, which blocks if queue is empty.

Comment: Could you please update your answer with your queue-based solution for a general case with N and K < N ?

Answer (score 0):

I would create three `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)

and with a Factory delegate each execution for any of the executors.

```
ExecutorService executor = ThreadFactory.getExecutorForRequest(RequestType type);
executor.execute(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Requests are processed concurrently.

You may use Executor service.

> There are at most K requests to be processed concurrently at the same time.

In executor, set the maximum number of threads.

> Requests of the same type cannot be processed at the same time.

You may think to have different locks for each request type. Just make sure that if a thread is not able to get the lock for a request for a designated time, it should yield and go for next task processing.

Comment: Would you elaborate on the locks you proposed to meet constraints #3 ?

Answer (score 0):

The domain of your problem can be modelled into two data structures, which I have called **pending** (which maps types to unbounded queues of tasks - this is where tasks wait to be run), and **running** (where at most one task per type ready to be run, or actually being run by an Executor).

The K constraint must be applied to *running*: it has at most K `Type` to `Task` mappings.

The highlight is that the number of threads you allocate for all the task processing is entirely orthogonal to the concurrency constraint handling: your thread pool choice should be dictated (among other things) by the type of tasks to be performed (IO/CPU bound?), not by the concurrency constraints.

An implementation:

```
public class Foo {

    enum TaskType { A, B, C }

    class Task {
        TaskType type;
        Runnable runnable;
        volatile boolean running;
    }

    Map<TaskType, Queue<Task>> pending = new HashMap<TaskType, Queue<Task>>();

    Map<TaskType, Task> running = new HashMap<TaskType, Task>();

    ExecutorService executor = null; // Executor implementation is irrelevant to the problem

    /** Chooses a task of a random type between those not running. */
    TaskType choosePending(){
        Set running_types = running.keySet();
        running_types.removeAll(Arrays.asList(pending.keySet()));
        List shuffled = new ArrayList(running_types);
        Collections.shuffle(shuffled);
        return (TaskType) shuffled.get(0);
    }

    // note that max concurrency != parallelism level (which the executor is responsible for)
    final int MAX_CONCURRENCY = 3;

    void produce(){
        synchronized(running){
            if (running.size() < MAX_CONCURRENCY) {
                synchronized (pending){
                    TaskType t = choosePending();
                    running.put(t, pending.get(t).remove()) ;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) produce();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    Task chooseRunning(){
         for (Task t : running.values()){
             if (!t.running){
                 return t;
             }
         }
        return null;
    }

    void consume(){
        final Task t;
        synchronized (running){
            t = chooseRunning();
            if (t != null){
                t.running = true;
                executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        t.runnable.run();
                        synchronized (running) {
                            running.remove(t);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) consume();
            }
        }).start();
    }

}
```